# Subject-Verb Agreement: The horse and carriage is ready

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

A rule in my text book says

> If the 2 subjects separated by 'and' refer to the same thing/person/suggest the same idea, they take a singular verb.
>
> E.g. **The Horse and Carriage *is* ready**

I feel that the sentence should be -

> The Horse and Carriage are ready

And Grammarly agrees with me -

> [image: Grammarly screenshot saying "it appears that the singular verb "is" does not agree with the plural compound noun "The horse and carriage"]

So what does the subject agree with? 'Is' or 'are'?

Comment: I would use "are", although it's been a long time since I announced a horse and carriage. I agree with Grammarly's explanation. A compound subject consisting of distinct items is plural. "The car and driver are ready" is correct, but "the car with driver is ready" is also correct.

Comment: @EdwardBarnard Not necessarily. "Liver and onions is my least favorite entree." It depends on whether "horse and carriage" is being viewed as one thing (the carriage pulled by a horse is ready" or two separate things (the horse is ready, and so is the carriage).

Comment: @ColleenV - good counter example. You are certainly correct. We can *use* singular or plural to indicate whether the compound subject should be thought of as one thing, or multiple things.

Comment: The  horse and carriage are ready. A horse-and-carriage economy is a  thing of the past.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of which one?

Comment: @metaturso There should be a link in a box at the top of the question to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151717/in-the-sentence-drinking-and-driving-is-dangerous-why-does-the-verb-to-be

Comment: Google Ngram Viewer shows 'horse and carriage is' and 'horse and carriage are' about equal in usage, and also 'was/were' and 'horse and cart is/are/was/were'.

Comment: The "liver and onions" example is irrelevant since the predicative complement "entrée" is singular -- hence singular agreement is normal. In your "horse and carriage" example, there is no predicative complement, so there's more flexibility. I would suggest that plural "are" is more appropriate.

Comment: Aha. I was completely blind to it.